# Flask cant initial my class when rendering the template

Tags: python, flask, flask-session

I use Flask:

```py
from flask import Flask, render_template, session
```

I want to package some session operation methods in a class like this:

```py
class Session:
    def __init__(self):
        self.ip = request.remote_addr
        self.name = request.remote_user
        session['ip'] = self.ip
        session['name'] = self.name
```

in order to render these two attributes in templates by the function below:

```py
@app.route('/', methods=['GET'], strict_slashes=False)
def indexpage():
    return render_template('index.html',s=Session())
```

However, different devices get the same output which means `Session.ip` and `Session.name` are the same from different devices. I think class `Session` is not initialized properly.

Comment: In `Session.__init__`, where does the variable `session` come from (e.g. in `session['ip'] = self.ip`)?

Comment: I am sorry about that.
session is a class from flask.

Comment: Did you check the ip and the name that you get from the `request` object? Jinja2 caches the templates, but probably not the data, and the scope of your variable `s` creates a new one for every request. So I would assume it comes from the data you get from `request`. For example, if you are using a reverse proxy with a bad configuration.

Comment: Absolutely yes. When I use `request.remote_addr`  in `render_template()` directly, it works fine.